# Adding page number to footnote citation

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

Is there a way to specify the page number to follow a footnote citation, so that I get something like, e.g.:

John Doe, LaTeX Manual (New York: Smith Publishing, 2003), 33.

I would like to be able to also cite the same book, but page 45 (e.g.) in a different place.

I'm using the `biblatex-chicago` style, notes and bibliography version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should read the `biblatex` documentation on how to use its `\cite` commands. All the  `\cite` commands (`\cite`, `\footcite`, `\parencite`, `\textcite`) and their variants allow for two optional arguments: a prenote and a postnote.  The syntax is:

```
\cite[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}
```

The page number is part of the postnote, so to get your example, you would type:

```
\footcite[][33]{Doe2003}
```

assuming Doe2003 is your cite key.

Comment: The first `[ ]` in Alan Munn's answer can be omitted: if any `\cite` command gets a single optional argument, it will take it for a postnote. Thus `\cite[p. 37]{mybook}` and `\cite[][p. 37]{mybook}` will both render to [7, p. 37] (or something similar depending on your bibliography style).