# Biblatex-Chicago and Biber not compiling

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style

For some time, I have been trying to get the `biblatex-chicago` style working but have failed miserably. I have made substantial efforts to examine the forums and other people's [biblatex-chicago and biber problem: unprocessed references, left with citation keys in pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66729/biblatex-chicago-and-biber-problem-unprocessed-references-left-with-citation-k), but they have not worked in solving my problem.

Here is the text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}


\title{Chapter 4}
\date{}  
\begin{document} 

\maketitle{}

Between July and September 1989, the trade fiasco with Saudi Arabia had claimed the    lives of almost 30,000 Australian sheep.\footcite{Release:N31990} 
Animal Liberation, the Federation, the World League for the Protection of Animals and the RSPCA unanimously called for an immediate cessation to the live sheep trade based on animal welfare concerns.\footcite{ALMAGJuly-Sep1990} 




\pagebreak
\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

And here is the error code that I get when I compile:

```
Process started: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe" "Chapter 4".bcf

data source C:\Users\Gonzalo\AppData\Local\Temp\par-476f6e7a616c6f\cache-    63038a22a6dc2bcfc65352f2f3a3448ce3f3ab68\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in.
```

The `log` file says that I have undefined references and that I should rerun Biber but this, obviously, fails. I am running the latest version of `TeXStudio` and `MikTeX` on Windows 7 (64bit). I have manually downloaded and installed `Biber` in the miktex\bin folder and have configured `TeXStudio` with "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe" %.bcf.
Any help (in simple language - I am a humanities student not an IT person) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to remove the files at ` C:\Users\Gonzalo\AppData\Local\Temp\par-476f6e7a616c6f\cache-    63038a22a6dc2bcfc65352f2f3a3448ce3f3ab68\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml`. You can remove the entire folder `par...`, and then run again biber

Comment: See also [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814).