# biber, why does my MWE not work?

Tags: biber, texniccenter

Please help me, I have no idea why this MWE does not work. I am using the TeXnicCenter.

I get the error message:
Citation 'author2000' on page 1 undefined on input line 29.

```
\listfiles                % shows used packages in a list in log file
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2000,
  author  = {AuthorA},
  title   = {Title of Article},
  journal = {Name of Journal},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear
 ,backend=biber         % to force biblatex to use biber
 ,sortlocale=de_DE
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

hi.\autocite{author2000}    

\nocite{*}              % all bib entrys are printed

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

geh.blg just says

> [0] Config.pm:320> INFO - This is Biber 1.9
>
> [0] Config.pm:323> INFO - Logfile is 'geh.blg'

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you try running `biber geh` from a command window and look if you are in the same situation as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119471/biblatex-chicago-and-biber-not-compiling ?

Comment: I compiled with `pdflatex` and `biber` ... the citation appears in the the bibliography, without error message

Comment: I was in the same situation as in the link of egreg. Deleting the "par-..." directory did solve the problem.
thank you very much!

Comment: @zwis: Shall this question be closed then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If this question is closed as a duplicate (I think it should, but we can wait a bit until the OP gets back to us) it should be of this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864.

Comment: @moewe: I did not yet vote ... It was just a question to the OP. I had the `off-topic ... question solved by comments ... blabla` closing reason in mind

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I realised that, I was just throwing this question in the ring (as the "proper" duplicate) should you decide to vote to close (and I thought you might keep an eye on this question as you asked the OP if it should be closed `:-)`).

Comment: @moewe: Yes, that's quite useful as possible closing.

Comment: @moewe It can be closed, I am happy about the quick and easy solution.