# biblatex-chicago TeXworks Bibdesk

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, chicago-style

I'm using TeXworks to compile a paper, but can't figure out how to include a bibliography page with the author-date format style. I want to refer to papers in the format (Author, YYYY) and in the bibliography to have author, then year. I was previously using `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` and my document was compiling just fine.

Now, I've downloaded a bunch of packages following David Fussner's instructions for the `biblatex-chicago` package, but for the life of me I can't make my document run. I have a bunch of other packages in the preamble that may be conflicting with `biblatex-chicago` (I've added them as I've needed to do things with figures, tables, footnotes at the end of the document, etc). 
Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{array,longtable,calc}
\usepackage{arydshln}
%
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
%
\usepackage[margin=65pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.jpg}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{newreferences.bib}
```

I'm citing using `\cite{Glomm1994}`and at the end I have:

```
\newpage
\printbibliography
```

I'm getting all sorts of errors. Once it actually ran, but with no bibliography page. I need some logic to follow when adding the packages necessary for `Chicago` style bibliography. There are so many options out there I no longer know what I'm doing.

Any help would be appreciated. I have a deadline and I've dedicated too much time on something that should be simple.

Comment: Welcome to the side. Please provide a minimal working example. (P.S. I'm going to bed now.) Also, you can highlight code by indenting each line by 4 spaces or by clicking on the botton with the curly braces above the editing window.

Comment: If you write `/cite{Glomm1994}` you will not get a citation; macro begin with a backslash---not a frontslash.

Comment: For guidance on how to use `biblatex`, see [What to do to switch to `biblatex`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and [biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864), specifically for `biblatex-chcago` see [Get `biblatex-chicago` working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30288/35864). From what I can see, the list of packages you load should not conflict with `biblatex-chacago` (you load `caption` twice though). If after reading the post above you still have trouble compiling, delete all temporary files, recompile, edit your question and post the relevant errors here.

Comment: Fixed some repeated calls for different packages, there is no need to load `booktabs` or `caption` more times than one call of `\usepackage{...}`. Try to check if the order/sequence of calls inside your preamble is right, then re-compile. If the problem persist, then you can focus only on the main error generated by the bib. and not the preamble.

Comment: The file as posted (+ a minimal `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`) will run without problems, so more information is needed.  Please post a **complete** (but minimal) example file -- most `\usepackage` calls here are irrelevant.  Some idea of what error messages you are getting would also be helpful.  Finally, note two things: `hyperref` should be among the last packages you load; and you should switch from using `\bibliography{newreferences.bib}` to `\addbibresource{newreferences.bib}`.

Comment: See these links for how to build a proper minimal (non-)working example: [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) and [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl).

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. Here's the minimal example (I incorporated the changes suggested):

Comment: HERE'S THE MINIMAL EXAMPLE:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
 The inclusion of these two productive roles of government opens the door to the analysis of how taxation and the structure of government spending affect the level of output and human capital accumulation \cite{Holden2012}.  
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}


AND THE ERROR I AM GETTING IS:

! Package keyval Error: avdate undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
I.92 \csuse{cms@\cms@style}

Comment: You might want to include the MWE in your question. Your MWE however runs fine (I did not have `references.bib`, so I used another file and another entry not `Holden2012`) on my setup. Try an update. What version of `biblatex`, `biber`, `biblatex-chicago` do you have installed?

Comment: Moewe,thank you! I had MacTex 2012, updated to 2013 and it works!! :D

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is due to an out-of-date installation.