# Suppressing large text "Works Cited" in biblatex-mla `\printbibliography`

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I'm trying to create an MLA citation page using [`biblatex-mla`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla?lang=en). However, the `\printbibliography` command creates a 16-point (uncertain as to exact size), left-justified, Times header "Works Cited" rather than the header that's being created by the mla.sty that I'm using.

Is it possible to suppress the "Works Cited" text generated by `\printbibliography`? [edit:] I would like the header text that's used to be removed completely, including the vertical space so I can have the 'title' of the bibliography produced separately.

Minimum example showing unwanted header on second page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]\autocite{Saussure1995}

\lipsum[2]\autocite{Labov1972}

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

For the file saved as `mla_minimum_citations.tex`, I compiled with:

```
latex mla_minimum_citations && biber mla_minimum_citations && latex mla_minimum_citations && pdflatex mla_minimum_citations
```

(Minimum example adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30288/104015)

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these lines to your preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {Bibliography},%
  references= {References},%
}
```

or whatever names you want.

[image: demonstration of changed text in bibliography heading]
If you don't want a title for your bibliography, to prevent any side effect that might result from redefining these strings as empty strings, it would be better to use the optional argument of `\printbibliography`:

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

Comment: Setting both fields `={}` causes there to be an empty vertical space. Is there a setting to suppress the use of the BibliographyStrings in `\printbibliography`?

Comment: @user2943160: I've completed my answer for this special case.

Comment: The second option still seems to require setting `bibliography` and `references` to empty strings to work correctly. Otherwise, the `Works Cited` text reappears, just raised higher on the page.

Comment: @user2943160: Finally, it's much simpler. It can be done with the `heading` key. Please see my updated answer.