# Trouble with displayquote and page numbers for citations

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber, csquotes, subfiles

I have a problem trying to get a citekey to work properly in a blockcitation. I have a nested file setup via the subfiles package and using csquotes to generate the block quote as follows:

In the subfile I have the following setup:

```
\documentclass[draft,../../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document} 
\begin{displayquote}[\cite[235]{SomeOne}]
Something smart.
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

And in the main document I have the csquotes package loaded as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,draft]{memoir}
% more preamble
\usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage[
   backend=biber,
   style=authoryear-icomp,
   maxcitenames=2,
   sorting=nyt
   ]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
   \subfile{sub.tex}
\end{document}
```

Now, when I compile either the mainfile or the subfile, I get the following error message:

> ! File ended while scanning use of \blx@citeargs@i.
>   
>   \par
>   sub.tex
>   I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
>   to read past where you wanted me to stop.
>   I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
>   you'd better type`E' or `X' now and fix your file.
>   ! Emergency stop.
>   sub.tex
>   (job aborted, no legal \end found)

If I omit the post-note "[235]" in the argument for `\cite` above, the error-message disappears. I can't figure out what exactly is going on, besides the fact that it compiles fine without the post-note. I can't see whether it is wrong syntax or what is going on. I did just as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11784/adding-page-number-to-footnote-citation), but it does not apparently work that way. By the way, in my bibfile for the entry cited, I have not put any pagenumber information or anything, I don't know if this is what is causing the error-message?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: See also [\] inside an optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/35864), [Bug? LaTeX misparses nested optional arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78414/35864), [LaTeX: optional arguments with square brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84595/35864)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is located in this line:

```
\begin{displayquote}[\cite[235]{westfahl:space}]
```

The problem here is that LaTeX has a problem to find the corresponding closing `]` and `}`.  To avoid this just enclose the parameter inside `[...]` with an own grouping pair of `{..}`. Result:

```
\begin{displayquote}[{\cite[235]{westfahl:space}}]
%                   ^^                          ^^
```

Please see the other changes I did to make your code compilable. Please compare my MWE with your code and stud the changes ...
So, with the following compilable MWE (using package `filecontents` to have all file included in one compilable MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-sub.tex}
\documentclass[\jobname.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document} 
\cite[235]{westfahl:space}
\begin{displayquote}[{\cite[235]{westfahl:space}}]
Something smart.
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,draft]{memoir}
% more preamble
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxcitenames=2,
  sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Test
\subfile{319085-sub}
Test
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: Gosh ... Thank you!